# Illustrator - cutting away with a mask

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have this [illustration](https://www.dropbox.com/preview/Phils%20Shares/Screenshot%202019-04-27%20at%2012.26.11.png?role=personal) in paths. I want to erase the bottom of the wrist so it's inside the purple oval, but the top finger is outside the oval, so it looks like the hand is coming out of the oval.

Using the eraser tool by hand is not going to give me smooth curve. How do I erase that wrist just up to the oval neatly?

Im a PS user but in Illustrator I just cant seem to find a way. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: There's no image and your link appears to be behind a log in wall.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use the Shape Builder tool.

1. Choose the Selection tool <kbd>V</kbd> to select all the shapes
2. Choose the Shape Builder tool <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, and mouse over the section of the artwork you want to remove.
3. Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and the cursor will change to a minus sign, click once to remove the highlighted section.

For example:

[image]

If you want to find out more about the Shape Builder tool, it's functionality is documented here: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creating-shapes-shape-builder-tool.html There are also several tutorials listed [on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Illustrator+shape+builder+tool+tutorial)